# LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, dll, command-line, linker

I have been creating a DLL using the same script for months. However, today, it has stopped working and I cannot get it working again.

A few days ago I had to install various different programs, so my personal guess is that one of them messed with the environment variables and therefore I am getting that error. I say that because I know the %PATH% variable has been modified (I could not run php scripts either and I found out it was because the php installation path had been removed from the %PATH% environment variable).

From what I have found, it seems that I need to reference somehow the file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib
```

I tried searching for the file from C:/ and I got the following results.
[image]

I added all those paths to the %PATH% variable but it doesn't seem to work.

**Maybe I have to add the path to some specific environment variable?** (whose name I do not know...)

I am using "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt".

The linking call from my script is the following:

```
link /DLL /nologo /MANIFEST /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFESTFILE:.\name.dll.manifest /MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /OUT:name.dll name.obj /DEF:name.def
```

And I am getting:

```
LINK: Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: where/how did you modify %PATH%? you can't change it system-wide from a cmd.exe prompt via `set`, that only changes the var in that one shell.

Comment: The PATH environment variable is irrelevant, if you build from the command line then the LIB variable must be set correctly.  It is not very clear why you use a "script" when you have a nice IDE available.  Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to ensure the build environment is correctly initialized.

Comment: I modified it from "System properties > Advanced > Environment Variables". I also rebooted after that and it was not working.

Comment: @HansPassant got it working by creating the environment variables "LIB" and "LIBPATH" with value "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\". Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Guimo It also helped me. Thank you!